# Dependant datepickers

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two date fields, the maximum date cannot be before the initial date, so I disabled the pickupMaxDate, and enabled it again in `onChange()`. Right there I need to set the startDate param to the value selected in the first `DatePicker`

This is what i've tried:

```
<?=
$form->field($shipment, 'pickupDate')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true,
        'language' => 'es',
        'startDate' => '0d',
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
    ],
    'clientEvents' => [
        'change' => 'function (dateText, inst) {
            //-> WORKING
            $("#shipment-pickupdatemax").prop("disabled", false);

            //-> NOT WORKING
            var mindate = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); //-> PRINTS (Wed Sep 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST))
            $("#shipment-pickupdatemax").datepicker("option", "startDate", mindate);
        }',
    ],
]);
?>
<?=
$form->field($shipment, 'pickupDateMax')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true,
        'language' => 'es',
        'startDate' => '0d',
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'disabled' => true
    ]
]);
?>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `'onClose' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function( selectedDate ) {
      $( "#'.Html::getInputId($shipment, 'pickupDateMax').'" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
     }'),` or write on onchange

Comment: This documentation link will help you for dependant datepickers - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/yii2/6366/yii2-jquery-calendar-for-text-field#t=20160920103431861691

Comment: This all are different approaches of what i already have that is not working, tested them all and no luck.